# Is the mobile command center self-aware?

Tags: knight-rider, artificial-intelligence

I seem to recall at least one episode of Knight Rider in which the mobile command center (commonly referred to as the "semi") was seen driving itself in a manner similar to how KITT operates in Auto Cruise mode.

Was the command center truck self-aware like KITT, or was it simply a "dumb" driving program?

I'm not aware if this was ever mentioned or if anyone was ever seen conversing with the truck AI on the show; if there is no canonical answer I will accept any reasonable speculation as well.

Comment: +1 for the sheer cheekiness of calling Knight Rider "SciFi" :)

Comment: If artificial intelligence isn't sci-fi, what is? :)

Comment: @DVK The Hoff's perm could only have been achieved using alien technology- clear evidence of Sci-Fi :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [FLAG Mobile Unit](http://knight-rider.wikia.com/wiki/F.L.A.G._Mobile_Unit) was fitted with an **autopilot** unit in Season 4, but it was not fully aware. The 'Rook' was always had a driver; this was [Reginald Cornelius III](http://knight-rider.wikia.com/wiki/Reginald_Cornelius_III) (RC3) in Season 4, but an unnamed driver in earlier seasons.